# How do I add a custom html.node--.html.twig based on content-type?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to override the default html.html.twig according to my custom content-type.
But I only get suggestions like:

```
* html--node--16.html.twig    
* html--node--%.html.twig    
* html--node.html.twig    
x html.html.twig
```

I have tried for file-name

```
html--node--content-type.html.twig
```

But this was not successful. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.4.x) to add another suggestion, something like:

```
function THEME_theme_suggestions_html_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
    // Check it's a node page.
    if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
        // Insert as second to last so the more specific template by ID still works.
        array_splice($suggestions, count($suggestions) - 1, 0, 'html__node__' . $node->getType());
    }
}
```